# Is there a function that if my test fails I get a screenshot of it in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I want a screenshot as soon as I enter the wrong password

```
namespace UITest. 
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Firefox
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void AMDP()
        {
            Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://Google.de");

            Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

            //Add Username
            Thread.Sleep(waitingTime);
            Driver.FindElement(SoeUser).SendKeys("TestUser");

            // Add password
            Thread.Sleep(waitingTime);
            Driver.FindElement(SoePW).SendKeys("Testpw");

        }
    }
}
```

My code looks something like this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18660838/1663001

Comment: I copied it first before and then after the code but unfortunately it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? @DavidG

Comment: The code looks incomplete. Please [edit] your question to include the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver,string pathWithFileName)
{
    try
    {            
        ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(pathWithFileName, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I'm just learning C# and I'm a bit overwhelmed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong too @Vemula Dheeraj

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? @Almir

Comment: @Almir Can you try this and let me know if this works?

ITakesScreenshot ts = (ITakesScreenshot)driver;
var screenshot = ts.GetScreenshot().AsBase64EncodedString;

MediaEntityBuilder.CreateScreenCaptureFromBase64String(screenshot, "screenShotNameand Path").Build();

Comment: The Part "MediaEntityBuilder" doesn´t work... @Vemula Dheeraj